# Array Clone bytes 10-40?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way i can do

```
var splice = byteArray.Clone(offset, length);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can copy the bytes,

```
byte[] splice = new byte[length];
Array.Copy(byteArray,offset,splice,0,length);
```

Answer (score 6):

If it is an option to use Linq:

```
var splice = byteArray.Skip(offset).Take(length).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Obligatory LINQ solution:

```
var splice = byteArray.Skip(offset)
                      .Take(length)
                      .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself doing this in many places: write a helper.

```
public static class ArrayExtensions {
  public static Array ClonePart(this Array input, int offset, int length) {
    if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
    if (offset <= 0 || offset > input.Length) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offset");
    if (length <= 0 || length > input.Length || length+offset > input.Length)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length");

    var output = Array.CreateInstance(input.GetType().GetElementType(), length);
    Array.Copy(input, offset, output, 0, length);
    return output;
  }
}
```

(This will work for any type of one dimensional array.)